# How to make key a variable in firebase updates with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```js
await updateDoc(salonRef, {
   variable: downloadURL
})
```

I want to use variable in object in key.
I want to know how.

Comment: You are probably looking for [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015). Just wrap the variable in `[]` like this: `{ [variable]: downloadURL }`

Comment: I tried too, but I get an error.

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Function updateDoc() called with invalid data. Invalid field path ([object Object]). Paths must not contain '~', '*', '/', '[', or ']'

Comment: I just forgot to enclose it in double quotidian! Resolved! Thanks!